# How can I make n*n buttons using an array at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#

It takes a number `n` from the user and makes `n`*`n` buttons for it on the form.
When I run the code, only the first row appears on form, instead of all `n` rows.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.ToString());
     Button[,] v = new Button[n, n];
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          int top = 60;
          int left = 160;
          int width = 25;
          for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
          {
               Button c= new Button();
               c.Top =top ;
               c.Left= left;
               c.Width = width;                 
               v[i, j] = c;
               left += c.Width + 2;
           }
           top += 2;
           left = 160;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
          {
               this.Controls.Add(v[i, j]);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the top variable at each loop, your buttons are all in the same top position. Move the initialization of the top variable outside the first loop

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    int top = 60;
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.ToString());
    Button[,] v = new Button[n, n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // int top = 60;
        ......
```

However, you are incrementing the top only by 2 pixel. This is not enough to avoid covering one row of button with the next row. You need to increment top by at least 25 pixels at the end of the inner loop.

```
        ....
        top += 25;
        left = 160;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use your `for` loops to set the `top` and `left` property values (more than one variable can be defined and incremented in a `for` loop).

For each `row`, we increase the `top` value by the `height + padding` (padding is the gap between buttons), and for each `col`, we increase the `left` by `width + padding`.

We can also add each button to the controls collection as we create it rather than adding it to an array and then iterating again over that array, and we can add some input validation to the `textbox.Text` that we're assuming is a positive number, presenting the user with a message box if they entered something invalid.

Given this, we can simplify the code to something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count;

    // Validate input
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out count) || count < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive whole number");
        return;
    }

    // remove old buttons (except this one)
    var otherButtons = Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b => b != button1).ToList();
    foreach (Button b in otherButtons)
    {
        Controls.Remove(b);
    }

    // Add button controls to form with these size and spacing values (modify as desired)
    var width = 25;
    var height = 25;
    var padding = 2;

    // For each row, increment the top by the height plus padding
    for (int row = 0, top = padding; row < count; row++, top += height + padding)
    {
        // For each column, increment the left by the width plus padding
        for (int col = 0, left = padding; col < count; col++, left += width + padding)
        {
            // Add our new button
            Controls.Add(new Button
            {
                Top = top,
                Left = left,
                Width = width,
                Height = height,
            });
        }
    }
}
```